# AWS Delete items by non-primary key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a problem, and i don't really know how to ask it

I've tables like this

```
user table
-----------------------------------
UID (primary key) | name (another key)
-----------------------------------
a1c8d3            | Hugo
f9e2d7            | Thomas
s2c9d4            | Damien
```

```
metadata table
-----------------------------------
MID (primary key) | UID (another key)
-----------------------------------
c3d9d3            | a1c8d3
d8f1e6            | a1c8d3
d3j5c2            | f9e2d7
```

I have a function to get all UID of my user table, they're store in an array

When i delete users of this array, i want to delete items on my metadata table which has same UID than my deleted users

Is it possible to delete items of my metadata table without using the primary key (here, MID) ?

Or did i need to set UID's of my metadata table to a global secondary index ? If yes, how can i do it ?

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

DeleteItem() requires a primary key for the table ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html))

You'd need to query the metadata table, and delete the rows with the matching UID.

If you don't already have it, I'd recommend a global secondary index with 
hash key = UID 
sort key = MID

Then a Query(GSI, hash = UID) would using your example data return two rows.
You'd then call DeleteItem(Table, HashKey = MID) for each returned row.

Or better yet, collect both deletes and send once as a [BatchWriteItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, we have find the solution